# Web3j - How to read the contract without credentials?

Tags: web3j, java

I'm using Web3j to interact with my deployed smart contract.

I've deployed my contract onto the testnet and can interact with it, however using the generated wrapper code, it requires my wallet.

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://testnet-endpoint-rpc.com"));
            Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                    "coolpassword1", "src\\main\\resources\\path-to-key-store.keystore"
            );

            FastRawTransactionManager txMananger = new FastRawTransactionManager(web3, credentials, 365);
            MySmartContract contract = MySmartContract.load(
                    "0x73292b80f99ffdc4e9a908865ce1d35fde7b736f", //Address for smartcontract
                    web3,
                    txMananger,
                    new DefaultGasProvider()
            );

//Reading from the contract
String contractName = contract.contractName(BigInteger.valueOf(0)).send();
```

How can I read from the contract without `credentials`